# syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY" error when trying to migrate postgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, django-migrations

I was using MySQL on my computer and when I wanted to host my app on a server I could not do it because the mysqlclient package needs root priviliges!! so I had to use something else so I used the postgreSQL database and It connected and ran the makemigrations but when I tried to run the migrate it gave me the 'syntax error on or at "WITH ORDINALITY"'. Does someone know what is causing the problem?? every time I try to run migrate it give me this error!!

Answer (score 1):

Your postgreSQL version is < 9.4 which is old and out of support, you should upgrade it

From Django 3.1 [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes)

> Django supports PostgreSQL 9.5 and higher. psycopg2 2.5.4 or higher is
> required, though the latest release is recommended.

Comment: Do you know how can I check the version of postgreSQL on cPanel?? And if it does turn out to be old version, should I use older version of django??? Because I cannot change the postgreSQL version on the server

Comment: I tried to install django 2.2.17 and did a migration after deleting the migration files and deleting the database and I made a new database and it did not work, do you think of any solution??

Comment: Django 1.11 is last version to support pg < 9.4 , it is highly advised not to use these versions both of pg and Django